# Map activity hiding new activity, drawer menu items can neither switch to another activity nor to a fragment on click

Tags: android

I am a beginner. My project contains an existing map activity that contains a navigation drawer. The Java code for both the activities are combined into one. I want to start a new activity/new fragment every time any menu item of the drawer is clicked but I am unable to do so.

Here is my activity_maps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main2"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main2_drawer" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.AppBarOverlay">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
     <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/frame">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity2" />
          </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="137dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.PopupOverlay" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
                card_view:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="   #D3D3D3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Find Ambulances"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/ambu" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view1"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
                card_view:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="   #D3D3D3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Find Hospitals"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/hosp" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_view2"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                card_view:cardElevation="6dp"
                card_view:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="   #D3D3D3">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Search"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="115dp"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@mipmap/search" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

       </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


  </FrameLayout>
```

MapsActivity2.java:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener,NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

  GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
  SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
  LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
 GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 Location mLastLocation;
  Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);

    //getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) 
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
      findViewById(R.id.fab);
    /*fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
       Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
      findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.getBackground().setAlpha(120);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
  navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener
 ((NavigationView.OnNavigationSelectedListener) this);
 }

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates
  (mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) 
   this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.
     PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates
 (mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, 
 (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), 
    location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");


 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker
(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

}



public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't 
       block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, 
      please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new 
       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, 
              int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity2.this,
                                    new String[] 
         {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
   }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] 
       grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
    {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    return true;
}




@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void displaySelectedScreen(int id) {


}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_c) {
        // Handle the camera action


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_g) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,KnowActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Value Send","this data sent");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_s) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_feed) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }



    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

         }

     }
```

KnowActivity.java:

```
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class KnowActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_know);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String dataSentFromMain = bundle.getString("Value Send");

        Toast.makeText(this, dataSentFromMain, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: When presenting several files here, please separate them using an introductory title, as per my edit, otherwise they will appear to have merged into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Going to need some more context here bud.  BE good to see the java code you have already but here is how you can go about showing a new fragment overtop of an existing activity...

```
NewFragment someFrag = new NewFragment();
getSupportedFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.YourActivity, someFrag).addToBackStack("")
      .commit();
```

This will replace the activity layout you define by `R.id.YourActivity` and replace it with whatever fragment you supplied in `someFrag` this will also add this activity to the backstack so when a user is on the new fragment and presses the back button, it will return to this activity.

Hope this helps but it's hard to give a clear cut answer to the problem with such little context

Comment: else if (id == R.id.nav_g) {
        Intent intent= new Intent(this,KnowActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Value Send","this data sent");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        this.startActivity(intent);

Comment: why i can't switch to KnowActivity.java the code of which i have posted with the menuitem click ?